# Advantages of static function collections

Tags: javascript

I am sure this has been asked before, but not able to find it ... so I'll give it a try.

Wen coding projects that consist of multiple domains I usually divide them into two groups.

1. If it should be only one instance – ever – I use static objects. Utilities also quickly land here.
2. Else use prototype.

As an example I have a project where there a cache is maintained. As there should only be one cache it is typically written as:

```
var cache = {
    head : null,
    tail : null,

    clear  : function () { 
        cache.head = null;
        cache.tail = null;
        ...
    },
    add    : function () { ... },
    remove : function () { ... },
    ...
};
```

Or something like:

```
var cache = {};
cache.push = function (d) {
  ...
};
cache.flush = function (d) {
  ...
};
```

Other objects are meant to be duplicated, or might one day be, and are coded as:

```
function Foo() {
  ...
}

Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
   ...
};
```

---

Now; my question is if there are any particular disadvantages with this practice. In particular the way of producing static objects. Or, put the other way around; any particular advantages. Most things I find discuss the advantages of prototype when duplicating objects. Use of prototype instead of `this`in constructor etc. Few address the particulars of static objects. Perhaps because it is straight forward?

Another example of static practice is e.g. [glMatrix](http://glmatrix.net/), for example with [vec2](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/blob/master/src/gl-matrix/vec2.js).